# Return an Image in Jersey Response

Tags: java, image, tomcat, jersey, response

I need to return an Image (as Stream) in one of my applications. After a short google i found a simple solution, but it only works for Opera and Chrome. Firefox and Safari will show a simple text with the info that the response is a stream.

Here's how i do it right now:

```
@GET
@Path("/getImage")
@Produces({
     "images/gif", "images/png", "images/jpg", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
})
 public Response getImage(@QueryParam("width") Integer width, @QueryParam("height") Integer height) {

     //SOME UNRELEVANT STUFF...

     String mmcpath = gi.filepath;

     BufferedImage image = ImageUtil.getImageFromPath(mmcpath);

     if (image != null) {

         // resize the image to fit the GUI's image frame
         image = ImageUtil.resize(image, width, height);
         InputStream is = ImageUtil.getStreamFromImage(image, FileHelper.getFileSuffix(mmcpath));

         if (is != null) {
             return Response.ok(is).build();
         } else {
             return Response.noContent().build();
         }
     }



     return Response.noContent().build();
 }
```

I hope someone has an idea how i have to change this method to get it working with the other browsers too.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did some more research and was able to fix my issue. (Note: I think this isn't 100% jersey)

First you have to define following two vars in your controller:

```
@Context
HttpHeaders header;
@Context
HttpServletResponse response;
```

After that you can handle the image-return with following code snippet:

```
//The mmcpath is the path to the image
BufferedImage image = ImageUtil.getImageFromPath(mmcpath);

if (image != null) {

    image = ImageUtil.resize(image, width, height);

    response.setContentType("images/jpg");
    response.setHeader("Content-Type", FileHelper.getNameFromPath(mmcpath));
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + FileHelper.getNameFromPath(mmcpath) + "\"");

    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", out);
    out.close();

    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

And here's the code i use in my ImageUtil.getImageFromPath(mmcpath); Just to complete the whole stuff.

```
ImageIO.read(new File(path))
```

I hope someone else can use these snippets too!

Comment: Great example!  You should paste in your ImageUtil resize method too just for completeness.